# Handling preflight requests in TIBCO BW

Tags: cors, tibco

How can we handle preflight requests in TIBCO BW. I have a web application which is sending AJAX request to my BW service. In the browser I can see before it actually sends the data it sends a request of type "OPTIONS" and gets a 200 status back, but the strange thing is I do not see any process in my BW getting triggered?

How does BW handles this. I am using basic HTTP Receiver as my process starter. By the way I am sending the CORS headers back in my response , but in this case request is not even reaching my service .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can only be achieved in BW 5.12 or later.
You need to add a property in BWEngine.tra file. The property is `bw.plugin.http.enableDoOptions.`
Set this to true.

This information is also available on BW 5.12 release notes